# [golang reverseproxy and gin]Error Handling in the reverseproxy source

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

sorry for my poor English and golang.
I'm trying to reverse proxy a file(video or picture,I know maybe the reverseproxy library isn't suit) with `gin` and the `net/http reverseproxy` library ,and I found some questions in the library source or my implementation.

- Cancel the downloading file will cause `p.copyResponse` return a `context cannel` error and panic in the `ServeHTTP` function.I think the content cancel behavior is accepted and it should be only logging 500 status code instead of panic.
- I can't get any useful information when touching off the `http.ErrAbortHandler` panic.(the only way I can use is to add breakpoint to `reverseproxy.go`)I think  it's necessary to add a `p.logf` function to log the real error.(There is a `shouldPanicOnCopyError` function can print log but it is seems just be used in test)
- Also in the same code block,it's seems that the custom ErrorHandler can't handle the err from `copyResponse`.Should `ErrorHandler` be added in there?

I found the `downloading file context cancel` and `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`(I can't capture this error again) will touch off `net/http Handler` panic without any useful log.(and gin will warning `Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 20X with 500`)

This is the raw code.

```
err = p.copyResponse(rw, res.Body, p.flushInterval(res))
if err != nil {
    defer res.Body.Close()
    // Since we're streaming the response, if we run into an error all we can do
    // is abort the request. Issue 23643: ReverseProxy should use ErrAbortHandler
    // on read error while copying body.
    if !shouldPanicOnCopyError(req) {
        p.logf("suppressing panic for copyResponse error in test; copy error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    panic(http.ErrAbortHandler)
}
```

This is the code I modified.

```
err = p.copyResponse(rw, res.Body, p.flushInterval(res))
if err != nil {
    defer res.Body.Close()
    // Since we're streaming the response, if we run into an error all we can do
    // is abort the request. Issue 23643: ReverseProxy should use ErrAbortHandler
    // on read error while copying body.
    if !shouldPanicOnCopyError(req) {
        p.logf("suppressing panic for copyResponse error in test; copy error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    //I don't think it is a good solution
    p.logf("error occur in copyResponse:%v",err)
    if err==context.Canceled{
        rw.WriteHeader(500)
    }else{
        panic(http.ErrAbortHandler)
    }
    //or this
    //p.getErrorHandler()(rw, req, err)


}
```

Thank you for your help!